# Use all GPU devices available for tf.estimator.Estimator().predict()

Tags: tensorflow

I am running a model with tensorflow 1.12, I am using the tf.estimator.Estimator API along with MirroredStrategy as train strategy.

The train and evaluate methods from the estimator work just fine, using all available devices to produce the results. However, when I try to use predict to get the logits produced by my model, I only see activity in the first available GPU device. I am using predict to process my validation set, and gather the resulting logits, and using just one device to do that is not efficient in my case.

So my question: is there any way to specify a distribution strategy to the predict method, so I can make use of all the available GPUs to obtain my result?

Thank you in advance.